# Best Method to Migrate /www Folder and mariadb

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, mariadb

I have a server running under Centos 7 with Raid 10 SATA disks (4TB), I have MSA2040 and created a volume for my server (Raid 6 - 10TB SAS).

I have formatted and created partition to be able to use this volume on my server. Now I am able to use it normally.

It communicates with 8 Gbps fibre channel.

What I want to ask is; Current I created a directory on `/msaStorage/myFolder` and created a link to this folder in my apache folder.

Current setup is:
`/msaStorage/exampledomain.com` is linked to `/var/www/exampledomain.com` (alias)

I can use it without any problem but is there any efficient method should I use? like creating an alias directly in apache config? Or is it logical to use **Apache Mesos**? Also I am planning to migrate my database to this volume, should I follow [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11884/move-data-folder-and-drive-mysql-centos) guide?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite follow you, but in general using symlinks to relocate data is something you want to avoid. When you add storage to a server you typically either:

- add the new storage to an existing LVM volume group:

  - which allows you to **extend the existing** volumes/file-systems (that means I don't have to copy data, don't have to worry about permissions or even downtime)
  - also allows you to **create new** volumes/file-systems and mount them where you need them
- create a new LVM volume group which:

  - also allows you to **create new** volumes/file-systems and mount them where you need them

Normally you don't turn new storage into a single filesystem at a random mount point to then move some of your data to that new file-system and point symlinks from the old location to the new.  (moving large datasets from one file-system to another can be time consuming, cause downtime and having your data at non-default locations requires some extra care with regards to SELinux.)

Comment: Not to mention he should probably have multiple LUNs anyway.

Comment: @HBruijn Thank you very much for explanation, since my system is still under testing phase I can migrate the data without worrying. I didn't want to extend the existing volume since the disks are SATA and storage has SAS. So I created a new volume and mounted it, that is what my current setup is. Since I am a more softwre than hardware and server config(this is my own garrage project) I just wanted to ask which method were best to migrate all my data to the storage's volume. I didn't turn whole storage into single file system, the size I mentioned is reserved for this server.